# How to Set 755 in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, chmod

Google Sitemap Plugin for Wordpress requires 755 permission for sitemap.xml file which is under the root directory of my site. Which CHMOD command should I use to change its setting to 755?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command you need is:

```
chmod 755 sitemap.xml
```